# Linear program solutions with three decision variables

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose we have a linear program which has exactly three non-negative decision variables
x1, x2, x3 and exactly three functional constraints, each containing a single variable: xi ≤ 1,
i ∈ {1, 2, 3}.

How do we find the number of basic and feasible solutions exactly and check for degeneracy?

Comment: Have you drawn out the picture?

Comment: I thought of adding slack variables: x1+s1 = 1, x2+s2=1, x3+s3 = 1 and then you can make one basic feasible solution but not sure how to continue from there finding all and basis for each solution.

Comment: Since there are 3 variables and 3 constrains btw, does this just mean that there are 3 nCr 3 = 1 solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At most one of $x_i\ge0$ and $x_i\le1$ can be tight for each $i$. To get a basic solution, with three tight constraints, we have to choose for each variable *which* of the two constraints is tight – exactly one for each variable. This gives us $2^3=8$ basic solutions. They may all be easily checked to be feasible and non-degenerate.

Comment: thank you, I can work from this!